# how does the beta function make the total probability of Dirichlet distribution integrate to 1?

Tags: self-study, distributions, beta-distribution, dirichlet-distribution, integral

the Dirichlet distribution $$Dir(\boldsymbol\mu|\boldsymbol\alpha)=\frac{1}{B(\boldsymbol\alpha)}\prod_K\mu_k^{\alpha_k-1}$$

How is the normalization term $B(\boldsymbol\alpha)$ calculated?
or in other words how can I show that the total probability integrates to 1?

I tried searching relevant textbooks and pages, but they all seem to just put down the equation there directly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [These lecture notes](http://www.univ-orleans.fr/MAPMO/membres/zins/Vietnam/PUF/courses2007-2008/HCMC_course-Emilion.pdf) might be helpful. If you figure out the solution, I'd encourage you to post it here as an answer to your own question.